# Audio quality poor when screen is off

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, audio, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I've noticed that recently the audio quality on my Galaxy note 3 becomes very choppy when my screen is off, but instantly fixes itself when the screen turns back on. Once the screen turns off the quality goes back down after a few seconds. This did not happen before.

I normally listen on Bluetooth headphones, but this problem still occurs with regular headphones and even just the phone spearer.

What could be causing this and how can I fix it? My suspicious is that some sort of process is running when my screen is off that is causing lag, but this feels doubtful because my phone doesn't get hot, nor my battery go down more than usual.

Comment: @Why_SE_bulling_new_users Version 4.4.2. So far I've only used my podcast app, podcast addict.

Comment: Have you changed any of the settings that relate to processor speed when the screen is off?

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was constant stuttering when using the excellent PodcastAddict app.  Try shutting down other apps that are running in the background and you may find the real problem:

I force-stopped the Xfinity wifi app I also had on my phone and it finally solved this incredibly frustrating problem!

(still using Note 2, Android 4.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

download any hibernation app (like greenify) hibernate apps and problem will be solved.
I did'the in note2 4.4.2.